# How to migrate Markdown files to Emacs org mode format

Tags: org-mode, markdown

I've got hundreds of personal notes stored as files in Markdown format, after several years using the [VoodooPad](https://plausible.coop/voodoopad/) personal wiki software for OS X.

There's plenty of information available for exporting from org mode to Markdown, but is there an easy way to convert Markdown to org mode format?

---

**Update**

Thanks to [user2619203's answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/5467/3914) and [this answer to a question on batch processing of files with Pandoc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10323583/705157) I was able to convert four hundred Markdown  files into org mode format in just a few minutes.

The solution was to export the VoodooPad document to a folder as text (**File** > **Export Document** > **Export as Text...**). Then call `pandoc` via the `find` command to convert them all in one go:

```
$ find . -name \*.txt -type f -exec pandoc  -f markdown -t org -o {}.org {} \;
```

The converted .org files I've looked at are formatted beautifully -- even the codeblocks and format styling. Thank-you, [user2619203](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/3928/user2619203).

To simply convert one file from Markdown to Org the following command can be used:

`pandoc -f markdown -t org -o newfile.org original-file.markdown`

[Here is a link to the Pandoc documentation](http://pandoc.org/README.html)

Comment: Since you are using `pandoc` you might be interested in `pandoc-mode` for emacs, its pretty neat

Answer (score 55, accepted):

[Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) can convert between multiple document formats.

To convert a bunch of Markdown files to org-mode:

```
for f in `ls *.md`; do 
  pandoc -f markdown -t org -o ${f}.org ${f}; 
done
```

Comment: Please consider adding more substance, such as a link to a relevant part of documentation, a particular `pandoc` command to use, a minimal working example. See [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). (In its present form this is more of a comment than an answer.)

Comment: Found the relevant documentation at http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html

Comment: Not related to pandoc, but for the shell, consider using `for f in *.md` instead of `ls *.md` for this purpose. See [the great bash wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) for a detailed explanation.

Comment: Also, using bash parameter expansion, we can remove the `md` extension so that the resulting files are just like "foo.org" instead of "foo.md.org":

`for f in *.md ; do pandoc -f markdown -t org -o "${f%%.md}".org "$f" ; done`

Answer (score 6):

Here is an emacs function that will convert the current buffer's content to orgmode format using pandoc:

```lisp
  (defun markdown-convert-buffer-to-org ()
    "Convert the current buffer's content from markdown to orgmode format and save it with the current buffer's file name but with .org extension."
    (interactive)
    (shell-command-on-region (point-min) (point-max)
                             (format "pandoc -f markdown -t org -o %s"
                                     (concat (file-name-sans-extension (buffer-file-name)) ".org"))))
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this new cool package: [org-pandoc-import](https://github.com/tecosaur/org-pandoc-import).

Answer (score 0):

A modification of the answer provided by the author that has the benefit of renaming `.md` files to `.org`, instead of to `.md.org`:

```bash
fd . -I --extension=md --type=f --exec bash -c 'pandoc -f markdown -t org -o "${1%.md}".org "$1"' - '{}' \;
```

Edit: this works by passing `'pandoc ...'` to bash as a command string through `bash -c`, which gives more flexibility than `--exec pandoc ...` in terms of string processing in this case.